# Cannot copy OTP code to clipboard in broadcast receiver on Redmi Note 9S (Android 12)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, clipboardmanager

##### Problem:

I am trying to copy the OTP code from an incoming SMS to the clipboard in a broadcast receiver. This is working fine on Galaxy A52s 5G but not on Redmi Note 9S.

##### Codes:

###### OTP Broadcast Receiver:

```kotlin
import ...

class OtpSmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        try {
            val bundle = intent.extras
            if (bundle != null) {
                val otpSms = getNewOtpSms(bundle)
                if (otpSms != null) {
                    val (otp, bank) = OtpSmsManager.getOtpFromSms(otpSms, true)
                        ?: return
                    if (otp.isNotEmpty() && bank.isNotEmpty()) {
                        copyOtpToClipboard(context, otp)
                        Log.i("SmsReceiver", "New OTP Code from $bank: $otp")
                        showOtpNotification(context, otp, bank)
                    }
                }
            } // bundle is null
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver: $e")
        }
    }

    private fun copyOtpToClipboard(context: Context, otp: String) {
        val clipboardManager =
            context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(
            ClipData(ClipData.newPlainText("otp_code", otp))
        )
    }

    private fun getNewOtpSms(bundle: Bundle?): OtpSms? {
        if (bundle != null) {
            if (bundle.containsKey("pdus")) {
                val pdus = bundle.get("pdus")
                if (pdus != null) {
                    val pdusObj = pdus as Array<*>
                    var message = ""
                    var date = ""
                    for (i in pdusObj.indices) {
                        val currentMessage = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdusObj[i] as ByteArray?, "3gpp")
                        } else {
                            SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdusObj[i] as ByteArray?)
                        }
                        message += currentMessage.displayMessageBody
                        date = currentMessage.timestampMillis.toString()
                    } // end for loop
                    return OtpSms(message, date)
                } else {
                    return null
                }
            } else {
                return null
            }
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

###### AndroidManifest.xml:

###### Permissions:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="true" />
```

###### Broadcast Receiver Tag:

```xml
<receiver
    android:name=".data.receiver.OtpSmsReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

###### Steps I have tried:

- I have checked the permissions and made sure that the broadcast receiver has the `READ_SMS` and `WRITE_CLIPBOARD` permissions.
- I have tried restarting the device.
- I have updated the app to the latest version.
- I have checked the device logs and there are no errors related to the broadcast receiver or the clipboard.

###### Question:

Why is the `copyOtpToClipboard()` function not working on Redmi Note 9S?

**Additional information:**

- The device is running Android 12.
- I am using the latest version of the Android SDK and Android Studio.

I tried to using Services to solve this problem but still this peroblem was..

**Expected behavior:**

When an SMS is received, the broadcast receiver should copy the OTP code to the clipboard.

**Actual behavior:**

The broadcast receiver is receiving the SMS and extracting the OTP code, but the `copyOtpToClipboard()` function is not working.

Comment: XIAOMI devices have a lot of bugs and non standard behavior.